# CSS Hierarchy Issue | Although it is more specific, it is ignored

Tags: css, hierarchy

I am calling 2 different css files. Two css properties are conflicting. But this is ignored even though the 2nd css part is more specific. Where is the problem? I looked at the CSS hierarchy. But it was supposed to run smoothly this way...

I'm not sure if this problem is related to the order of calling the CSS file.

[image]

Ignored

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    div.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile>.fb_dialog_content iframe:not(.hs-form-iframe) {
       width: 60px !important;
       height: 60px !important;
    }
}
```

Acceptable

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    iframe:not(#tidio-chat-iframe):not(.hs-form-iframe) {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the hierarchy details and solved the problem. If anyone else has this problem later, I leave the solution here. No matter how specific the selector is in CSS, the ID selector is always more dominant. To fix the problem, I just had to add id to the ignored CSS. I figured it out with the [specificity calculator](https://www.codecaptain.io/tools/css-specificity-calculator). It works perfectly now.

[image]

[image]